# R data.table How to obtain the VALUE from one of many columns (by column NAME), based on the value of another column

Tags: r, data.table, lookup

I am trying to extract a specific value, from a data.table in R, by referencing the column name

```
require(data.table)

# Create data.frame

cohort = c("cohort1", "cohort2", "cohort3")
year = c(2019, 2018, 2020)
item_2018 = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma")
item_2019 = c("banana", "apples", "oranges")
item_2020 = c("Tim", "Daniel","Simon")
desired_result = c("banana", "beta", "Simon")  # the values in this column I want to programatically grab from the relevant column before

cohorts <- data.frame(cohort,year, item_2018, item_2019, item_2020, desired_result)



setDT(cohorts) # turn the data.frame into a data.table

setkey(cohorts, year)  # setting the key for the data.table (not sure if this is necessary)


# CALCULATE NEW FIELD (attempts - not working)

# trying to populate new column "result_attempt_1" with : c("banana", "beta", "Simon")

cohorts[, result_attempt_1 := get(paste0("item_", year)), by = year] # this returns c("Simon", "Simon", "Simon") rather than  c("banana", "beta", "Simon") 

cohorts[, result_attempt_2 := .SD[, get(paste0("item_", year)), by = year]] # very wrong

cohorts[, result_attempt_3 := .SD[, get(paste0("item_", year)), by = get(paste0("item_", year))]] # very wrong
```

I want the values in the column "desired_results" to end up in the "result_attempt" columns. The closest I have got is the last correct result being repeated for each record/row.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be a row/column indexing

```
cohorts[, result := as.data.frame(.SD)[cbind(seq_len(.N),
      match(year, sub("item_", "", names(.SD))))], .SDcols = 3:5]

cohorts
#    cohort year item_2018 item_2019 item_2020 desired_result result
#1: cohort2 2018      beta    apples    Daniel           beta   beta
#2: cohort1 2019     alpha    banana       Tim         banana banana
#3: cohort3 2020     gamma   oranges     Simon          Simon  Simon
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is *a* something:

```
for (rw in seq_len(nrow(cohorts))) {
  set(
    cohorts, 
    i = rw, 
    j = "newcol", 
    value = cohorts[[paste0("item_", cohorts[["year"]][rw])]][rw]
  )
}

> cohorts
    cohort year item_2018 item_2019 item_2020 desired_result newcol
1: cohort2 2018      beta    apples    Daniel           beta   beta
2: cohort1 2019     alpha    banana       Tim         banana banana
3: cohort3 2020     gamma   oranges     Simon          Simon  Simon
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `data.table::melt`, match the item_year then lookup and update by reference:

```
cohorts[
    melt(cohorts, measure.vars=patterns("^item"), variable.factor=FALSE)[, 
        value[variable==paste0("item_", year)], by=.(cohort)],
    on=.(cohort), desired_result := V1]
```

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your helpful responses.

It seems the fundamental problem I was facing was in the data types of the columns in the data.table.

It seems that the "item_xxxx" columns were being coerced into FACTORS not CHARACTERS.

If we define the data.table from the start (rather than going through the data.frame stage) then the code I originally provided does indeed work fine.

```
require(data.table)

# Create data.table

cohort = c("cohort1", "cohort2", "cohort3")
year = c(2019, 2018, 2020)
item_2018 = c("alpha", "beta", "gamma")
item_2019 = c("banana", "apples", "oranges")
item_2020 = c("Tim", "Daniel","Simon")
desired_result = c("banana", "beta", "Simon")  # the values in this column I want to programatically grab from the relevant column before


# create DATA.TABLE (not data.frame)

cohorts <- data.table(cohort,year, item_2018, item_2019, item_2020, desired_result)

str(cohorts)


# setDT(cohorts)

# trying to populate new column "result_attempt_1" with : c("banana", "beta", "Simon")

cohorts[, result_attempt_1 := get(paste0("item_", year)), by = year] # this now returns c("banana", "beta", "Simon"), as desired

cohorts
```

So - take home message here - if something isn't working run str(data_name) to check the column data types.

thanks for the help and support, everyone.